# Okta SCIM Deprovisioning via PUT method?

Tags: okta, okta-api, scim, scim2

Our backend server doesn't support HTTP PATCH method (only PUT). As the result we cannot properly Unassign User from SCIM app.

When I try Unassign User, Okta SCIM seems make PATCH request (not PUT).
The [Okta SCIM docs](http://developer.okta.com/standards/SCIM/#deactivate-account-patch-usersid) says:

> Okta also does a PUT if the Patch is not supported for deactivation.

So, question is how can I switch  Okta SCIM app to make PUT instead PATCH?

Error message from Dashboard/Tasks tab.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but does your username really end in "coms"?

Comment: You might try their support if they're not answering on SO. :) http://developer.okta.com/ -> upper-right corner.

Comment: Yes, it ends with `coms` :) Thanks, will try to talk with support team.

Comment: They support PUT now. It seems they'll first make a PATCH request (according to my server logs, I'm service vendor dev). If they get an error back, they'll try PUT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OKTA doesn't support PUT right now for deactivation. They are going to implement that feature.